# Replace old timestamp with current timestamp in set of files

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

I have some files residing in a directory:

```
TESTRP_20201126220042.TAB
TESTRP_20201214145845.TAB
TESTRP_20210201145846.TAB
TESTRP_20210304134849.TAB
```

Here I need to replace the old timestamp with the current timestamp date `+%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

I tried to run the following code:

```
find . -type f -name '*TESTRP_*' -exec sh -c '
    now=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    for pathname do
        mv "$pathname" "${TESTRP}_$now.TAB"
    done' sh {} +
```

But its giving me single output file `_20210630083729.TAB` rather than three files with updated timestamp.

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using bash.

Comment: yes because you created single file name and using it in loop so everytime next file overrides the previous one. Even if you create now variable inside for-loop then it also wont work bcz your loop executes in ms so filename should also remains same.

Comment: I am fine if there is even a slight difference is timestamp or I can use sleep to keep some different , just need to change the filename with the current timestamp despite a difference of seconds in the timestamp.

Comment: And are all these files in the same directory, or different ones? (If the same, how do you prevent all of them from being renamed to the same new filename?)

Comment: yes these are in same directory as we are using timestamp with milliseconds, I assume there should be a way we can use a loop with some sleep function so that every file is different in terms of timestamp seconds

Comment: But your date timestamp doesn't include millseconds....

Comment: Every time we run date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S' it will give u different value for seconds, I am thinking of a way to calculate  TESTRP files set it in counter and using sleep change it to current date the loop will break if the count for files with name TESTRP is not found, once done I can replace the temp starting name with TESTRP. I have  been trying this no success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like

```sh
shopt -s extglob # Turn on bash extended globbing if not already enabled
for file in TESTRP_+([0-9]).TAB; do
    mv "$file" "${file/+([0-9])/$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}"
    sleep 1
done
```

which should rename one file a second. Alternatively, add a counter after the timestamp and increment it on every file:

```sh
shopt -s extglob
now=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
declare -i fileno=0
for file in TESTRP_+([0-9]).TAB; do
    newts=$(printf "%s%04d" "$now" "$fileno")
    mv "$file" "${file/+([0-9])/$newts}"
    ((fileno++))
done
```

Or it looks like some versions of `date` have a `%N` format for nanoseconds which shouldn't result in the same timestamp in any two calls of `date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S%N'`